# Upgrading Microsoft Graph to v1.7.0

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I notice there is a new version of Microsoft Graph (v1.7.0):

[image: Microsoft Graph]

I am using v1.6.2. How do I know what code changes (if any) will be required in my application and / or any DLL deplyment changes for it to work on clients computers?

Apart from simply upgrading and compiling and trial and error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot net SDK follows [semver.](https://semver.org) Which means a minor version upgrade will include new features but no breaking change which would require your code to be updated.
To know what's new in this version and if any action is required from you besides upgrading you can check the [release notes.](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/releases)